Add F1Score to model metrics in tensorflow
i want to add macro average of F1Score to model metrics in tensorflow and watch it at each epoch
i have add F1Score from tensorflow.metrics.F1Score in the following way, my task is binary classification but it returns None average of F1Score instead of macro average
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.F1Score(threshold=0.5, average="macro")])


Do you have a last Dense layer with one or two nodes? If you have only one node (which is usually enough for binary classification), this could be the problem, as F1Score seem to only work with one-hot encoded predicitions/labels.

yes, it is binary classification and i use sigmoid at the end. your answer is true. instead of tensorflow F1Score metric i creat a custom metric that calculate f1-score at each epoch end. thanks.
